# Pushing values into an object of array

Tags: javascript

So I have an array of objects called products:

```
const  products = [
   {
    name: 'Pants'
   },
   {
    name: 'Shoes'
   },
   {
    name: 't shirts'
    }
 ]
```

And the list contains a lot more products with other values apart from name. So suppose i forgot to give each product, (object) a coupon's array, it would take  me quite a while to update each object manually.

Is there a function that I can create which will push a coupons value into each object as an array?
So the final array would look like:

```
 const  updatedProducts = [
   {
    name: 'Pants',
    coupons: []
   },
   {
    name: 'Shoes',
    coupons: []
   },
   {
    name: 't shirts',
    coupons: []
    }
  ]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const updatedProducts = products.map(product => ({ ...product, coupons: [] }))
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can add properties in javascript like this:
`products.forEach(product =>   product.coupons = []);`